# Overriding the accessor and mutator method override

Tags: scala

From the Scala Cookbook, it is mentioned that if the constructor variable is not defined with 'var'or 'val', then by default Scala will not generate the accessor and modifier method, but in the below example.

```
1.  class Person2(name : String) {  
2.    def name = name;  
3.    def name_=(aName : String) {name = aName}  
4.   }
```

I am getting an compile time at line 2 as "overloaded method name needs result type". What does this mean? Am i overloading the name accessor method, but from the Cookbook the accessor and mutator methods are not generated. Can any one answer this please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note, that `class Foo(bar: String)` does not define a member variable named `bar`, only a constructor parameter. 
You can still use it everywhere in the class, because the entire class definition is inside the constructor body, so, it's essentially a closure, but you will not be able to assign values to it. So, if we fix the typo in the previous answer

```
class Person2(aName : String) {
   def name = aName
   def name_=(aName : String) = { aName = name }
 }
```

This will fail with a message "Reassignment to val".
This is because `aName` here is just a function (constructor) parameter, and all parameterс are always immutable, you cannot assign to them.

Moreover, if you try `new Person2("foo").aName`, it will also fail, because `aName` is not a member of `Person2`.

Now, to your question. Unlike java, methods in scala are in the same namespace as variables, so you cannot have both a variable and a method with the same name. That's what cases the compile error you are getting.

When you write `class Person2(val name: String)`, what you get is a private final variable `name` defined in the generated JVM class, that is not directly accessible in scala, and a method `name()`, that returns is value.

When you write `class Person2(var name: String)`, you again get a private (not final) JVNM class member, and two scala methods to access its value.

So, the "accessor methods" from the cookbook you mentioned refer to accessing the value of the member of the underlying JVM class, not the actual scala class being defined.

Finally, when you do `class Person2(name: String)` you are not creating any members of the class at all, so there is nothing to access.

Answer (score 0):

Scala compiler is confused here by the same name of both function and the class argument. This example works:

```
scala> class Person2(aName : String) {
     | def name = aName
     | def name_=(name : String) {aName = name}
     | }
defined class Person2
```

Comment: But why should it be confused, because here i have given the accessor method of the constructor parameter even though the method name is same as parameter name but both are pointing to the same thing.

Comment: You got the `name` and `aName` mixed up in the mutator. Try this: `new Person2("foo").name = "bar"` see how spectacularly it explodes :)

Comment: @Clashsoft  The edited version does not compile: `Reassignment to val`